# Microsoft Teams Tab X - Frame - Options

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, x-frame-options

I have created a Tab for Microsoft Teams. Once it is added to a channel it shows an error:

> Refused to display 'URL' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

The tab is supposed to load an application hosted in Azure which is making a connection to an external domain.

Comment: Pages loaded inside of a custom tab need to allow themselves to be iframed by Teams (via the X-Frame-Options and/or Content-Security-Policy headers). [Tab Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview#how-do-tabs-in-teams-differ-from-a-browser-viewing-the-same-content-url)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the following code into Global.asax fixed the problem:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
}
```

Comment: what if it's a dotnet core app?

Comment: @Benjamin `services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);`